# Canon Printer Web Interface Credentials

Tags: printing

Does anyone knows the default username/password to access a Canon Pixma Pro-100 printer from the WEB? e.g. When I type `http://10.165.16.100` in the address bar of IE I get a prompt to log on. I don't seem to be able to figure that out.

On a side note: The reason I'm trying to access the printer through the web interface is because it's not responding when sending a test page. Printer is installed on the print server with the latest driver and the correct port number (IP address above) and it's showing a status of Ready. When pinging the IP address, I'm getting replies even though there's no link light on the printer's NIC. Problem is happening on Win 7 and Win 8.

Here's the recorded event for the failing print document on the server (Win Serv 2012):

> The document Print Document, owned by adminxyz, failed to print on
>   printer Rewards Center - Canon Pro-100. Try to print the document
>   again, or restart the print spooler. Data type: RAW. Size of the spool
>   file in bytes: 9. Number of bytes printed: 0. Total number of pages in
>   the document: 0. Number of pages printed: 0. Client computer: GL0213.
>   Win32 error code returned by the print processor: 2147500037.
>   Unspecified error"

Comment: your question makes no sense, i've never seen a printer asking for a user name and password to enter it's interface. how is this information not in the manual?

Comment: Actually, In every organization I worked, whether the printer is a Ricoh, lexmark, or an HP, you have to provide a username and password to change the printers' settings using a web interface. Otherwise, anyone can and will make changes. This is the first time I work with a canon......

Comment: and how is this not in the manual? can you please post screenshots

Comment: Screenshot of what? A logon prompt for a webpage......

Comment: you're saying this printer is a network printer, you can plug in an Ethernet plug into it, and you're trying to connect to the printers interface, and it asks for a user name and password, i want to see that. Lastly, why do you keep avoiding my comment if you've read the manual or not?

Comment: I'm not having an argument with you, I'm trying to understand what you're looking at, since you can't do something as simple as a take a screenshot, try this: http://puu.sh/4zEYy.png

Comment: I cant give you screenshots because the problem happened at work and I'm home right now. You open IE and you type "http://10.xxx.xxx.xxx" (IP address of the printer. U have to do this from inside the company) and you hit Enter. At that point, you will be presented with a page which contains the same settings on the actual printer. Most networked printers have this capability. they all require username/password and the first time accessing the printer, you can use a default set (kinda like setting up a home router for the first time). thanks for the links, not what I need....

Comment: MANY printers have web interfaces;  almost all current Canon models provide this as the one and only way to configure some options. However, with the Pixma Pro-100, I believe that everything can also be configured from the printers display panel & buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't find any reference to the default credentials, but what I did find is that supposedly if you don't recall the administration password (their term for it), you should be able to click on "Help" at that screen and just follow the instructions.  Presumably they'll tell you how to reset it at that point, but there's no documentation on that either!

What I sometimes do in such cases is try "admin" with "admin", "password", and no password;  do the same for "administrator".  Unfortunately, that it isn't always one of those combinations, but those are the most common options.

Also, supposedly you can call Canon for support:
800-OK-CANON    800-652-2666  (specifically for Pixma Pro printers)

Comment: Debra, thank you for your help and I appreciate the fact that you put in some real effort into this answer. The default username and password turned out to be nothing. Just blank. Some of my coworkers changed them without adding his notes to the ticket!!!

Comment: You're welcome.  I was very surprised that the information wasn't out there somewhere!

Answer (score 14):

Username: ADMIN
Password: canon

*Case sensitive.

Comment: Can you provide a source for this answer?

Comment: Can verify this for Pixma Pro-10S

Comment: Works with Pixma 7550

Comment: Works with Canon MG7530

Comment: Correct for MG6650. Way too difficult to find this, Canon docs are wrong.

Answer (score 1):

From the [canon webmanual](http://ugp01.c-ij.com/ij/webmanual/Manual/W/MX490%20series/EN/AFG/afg_remoteui.html):

Entering Username and Administrator's Password
From the authentication screen, enter the Username and Password.
Username: ADMIN
Password: See "[About the Administrator Password](http://ugp01.c-ij.com/ij/webmanual/Others1/EN/PW/pw_default.html)."

Comment: External links can break or be unavailable, in which case your answer would be incomplete.  Please include the essential information within your answer so that the solution is self-contained, and use the link for attribution and further reading.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the info from 
http://ugp01.c-ij.com/ij/webmanual/Others1/EN/PW/pw_default.html
Note that BOTH the username AND the password are case sensitive, at 
least on the PIXMA Pro-100 model.  This information was ridiculously 
hard to find, and it wasn't in the setup instructions that came with 
my Pro-100 printer.  Also, I don't understand the reference in these 
instructions to a "PRO-100S" series.  That last "S" doesn't appear 
on my Pro-100 or in its literature.

> Model whose administrator password is specified as "canon": 
>   MG7500 series, MG6700 series, MG6600 series, MG5600 series MG2900 series,
>   MX490 series, MB5300 series, MB5000 series MB2300 series, MB2000 series, 
>   E480 series, E460 series 
>   iP110 series, iB4000 series, PRO-100S series, PRO-10S series 
>   At the time of purchase, the user name "ADMIN" is also specified for the 
>   models above. 
>   The following character restrictions apply to the password that you change: 
>   Set the password by using 4 to 32 characters. 
>   The allowed characters are single-byte alphanumeric characters. 
>   For security reasons, we recommend you use 6 and more alphanumeric characters.
>
> Model whose serial number is used as the administrator password: 
>   For the models other than the above, the printer serial number is used as
>   the administrator password.
>
> How to locate your printer's serial number:
>        http://ugp01.c-ij.com/ij/webmanual/Others1/EN/PW/pw_serial.html

Most of what I could find with web searches about locating my serial number 
was not correct for the Pro-100.  The serial number for this model (at least 
on my unit) was located inside.  Lift the lid as if you were going to change 
ink cartridges, and look inside on the metal rail to the right of the ink 
cartridge area and near to the front face of the printer.